# How to invert axis in Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using POI 4.1.0 to create charts but my bar chart is upside down

[image: Table Image]

[image: Chart Image]

How can I flip the chart?

```
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, col1, row1, col2, row2);
XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);
XDDFDataSource<String> dataSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
            new CellRangeAddress(startRow, data.getRows().size() + (startRow - 1), 0, 0));
XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(chartObj.getType(), bottomAxis, leftAxis);
XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
                new CellRangeAddress(startRow, this.data.getRows().size() + (startRow - 1), 
chartObj.getColumn(),chartObj.getColumn()));
XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(dataSource, values);
chart.plot(data);
```

Comment: have you considered just changing the order of the rows?

Comment: yes, if i change the order (DDD,CCC,BBB,AAA) the order in chart chage too (AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD), I would like the same order

Comment: I've not tried this but have you considered changing the range creation from `CellRangeAddress(startRow, this.data.getRows().size() + (startRow - 1)`  to `CellRangeAddress(this.data.getRows().size() + (startRow - 1), startRow` ?

Comment: I tried. "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid cell range, having lastRow < firstRow || lastCol < firstCol, had rows 4 >= 47 or cells 1 >= 1"

Comment: I just spotted `XDDFChartData.Series.setOrder()` have you tried that?

Comment: is a protected method, i can't access =(

Comment: That is the way Excel expects the data rows sorted for charts, which intuitively is the wrong one. If you do not believe it, try it in Excel! And then, as Excel uses this order, POI has to do it that way as well to be consistent/compatible.

Answer (score 1):

```
XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(...);
...
XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
bar.getCategoryAxis().setOrientation(AxisOrientation.MAX_MIN);
```

Comment: If you [edit] your answer and add an explanation to accompany your code, your answer will be more useful to people that read it.